# replace data from excel to access 2007

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, ms-access, sharepoint

I got an existing Access table with OLD data in some columns, and now I got an excel-file with NEW data inside the excel-file columns.
They tell me to replace the data in Access table with the new data from the Excel file.

Some of the rows in some columns in the Excel file are empty, and they tell me that if its empty, then don't replace it, let the old one be there.

I have tried google & find the answer to this, but I cant find it.
I cant find the SQL view either to write any code in Access.

Someone knows and can help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you first load the excel data in an Access table, so you can work better with it... and maybe cleanse it. Come back with some more specific problem. This is quite vague and broad, as stated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will be more specific.
I have now imported the excel data to a new Table in Access.
Now I have 2 tables next to each other.
I have one column its says "PHONE" on both tables, but on one of them, there is the new number . I want to replace the new number with the old number. This maybe work to do in Excel.

Comment: It can be done in Access... but you must state the table structure and the desired logic for the update procedure. How are you matching rows? Please revise the question and add more detail. As is this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

While you could do this in Access or VB, I think the easiest way would be to import the access table (Old Data) into a separate page in excel, so if you set up sheet 1 = new data, sheet 2 = old data then make sheet 3 = Required data,  a simple formula like =if(Sheet1!A1="",Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A1) dragged to match the table size should suffice.  Then check the data visually to make sure it seems good and paste the groomed data back into access.

The traps I can think of are where they use a space, rather than a blank cell, Where the rows don't line up through the addition of a person, (it is probably a good idea to sort the data appropriately)

Maybe save a backup before overwriting the old data.